# Symfony custom fields on add

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

On my Symfony2 project I got a list of arguments :

```
<ul class="arguments" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.arguments.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for argument in form.arguments %}
        {#<li>{{ form_row(argument) }}</li>#}
        <li>
            {{ form_row(argument.name, {'label': 'Name'}) }}
            {{ form_row(argument.french_description) }}
            {{ form_row(argument.english_description) }}
            {{ form_row(argument.return) }}
            {{ form_row(argument.type) }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I got a button "Add arguments", creating a new < li >< /li > with arguments fields. The problem is the new argument don't got the custom label "Name".

**EDIT :**
I add the arguments with a buton calling a JS function to add my fields on the page. Then when I click on submit it save it to database.

```
$('#add_argument_link').on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
    e.preventDefault();

    // setup an "add a argument" link
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>');

    // add a new argument form (see next code block)
    addArgumentForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    addTagFormDeleteLink($newLinkLi);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you add the new arguments? can you show the script that does it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('div#name_of_your_div');

        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        $('#add_argument').click(function(e) {
            addArgument($container);

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        if (index == 0) {
            addArgument($container);
        } else {
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        function addArgument($container) {
            var template = $container.attr('data-prototype')
                            .replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Argument number' + (index+1))
                            .replace(/__name__/g,        index);

            var $prototype = $(template);

            addDeleteLink($prototype);

            $container.append($prototype);

            index++;
        }

        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
            var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>');

            $prototype.append($deleteLink);

            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```